# SharePoint 2013 CSOM request timeout

Tags: c#, sharepoint, service, csom

A client has a Sharepoint 2013 farm consists of 2 servers acting as frontend and app and 2 SQL server (SQL14) all with windows server 2012.
My application is a windows application that calls sharepoint with CSOM requests.
All the environment was late by 10 min from the real time and for years everything was working, suddenly after fixing the time on the Domian sever so that it is fixed on all the severs and client machines, all the CSOM requests to sharepoint severs throws exception request aborted request timeout. Nothing is logged on the server and I couldn't find any reason.
Suddenly and by chance when I changed the IP on one of the PCs that holds my windows application to a one that was not in use, things started working again and I continued the same on all PCs.
But the client wants a clear justification on what was the problem.
Does anybody know how time is related to sharepoint and client.svc and is there any way the time keep cached on any level of the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was not a problem of sharepoint.
The client was using a new NSX system and for unkown reason it was causing packets loss. Basically net tcp requests packages.